# Can I apply a custom error message under an Antd input field on submit if a certain logic does not pass?

Tags: javascript, antd

I am trying to render an error message under an Antd input on form submit if some conditions are not satisfied. In my specific case, I want to render an error message if `!this.isNew && this.state.hasTypedLocation && !this.state.hasChosenLocation`. Right now I'm just console logging an error in the console. Does Antd offer some sort of similar functionality?

I have the following input:

```
    <Form.Item
      name="searchBox"
      rules={[
        {
          required: true,
          message: <IntlMessages id="common.error_address" />,
        },
      ]}
    >
      <Input
        type="text"
        placeholder={intl.formatMessage({ id: 'common.error_address' })}
        onChange={onChangeHandlerAddress}
        value={facilityData.address1}
      />
    </Form.Item>
```

And I have the following function which saves my entity:

```
  saveFacility(event) {
    event.persist();
    event.preventDefault();

    this.formRef.current
      .validateFields(['name', 'organization', 'customer', 'searchBox'])
      .then((values) => {
        const { actions } = this.props;
        const { facility } = this.state;
        if (!this.isNew && this.state.hasTypedLocation && !this.state.hasChosenLocation ) {
          console.log('error')
        } else {
          actions.saveFacility(facility);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a validator function that triggers the custom error message as a rule to Form.Item. The validator should return a Promise. Example:

```
<Form.Item
  name="searchBox"
  rules={[
    {
      required: true,
      message: <IntlMessages id="common.error_address" />,
    },{
      // Validator function example
      validator: (rule, value) => {
      if (!this.isNew && this.state.hasTypedLocation && !this.state.hasChosenLocation ) {
        return Promise.reject("Custom Error Message!!");
      } else {
        return Promise.resolve();
      }
    },
  ]}
>
  <Input
    type="text"
    placeholder={intl.formatMessage({ id: 'common.error_address' })}
    onChange={onChangeHandlerAddress}
    value={facilityData.address1}
  />
</Form.Item>
```